# Windows XP doesn't actually recursively change attributes

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, file-management

This should probably go into the question about Windows Annoyances, but can anyone explain why this happens, and how to fix it?

I right-click on a folder, select properties, and uncheck the Read-only.  Click on OK.  I get a confirmation with the option to apply changes to this folder only, or include subfolders and files.  I select the latter, and click OK.

Go back to properties, and it's still showing up as Read only.  Why?  I can't see any files that are still read-only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is described in **KB326549**: [You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, or in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549/)

The solution given there is to simply use the command-line `attrib` command to remove the attributes, like so:

```
attrib -r -s "c:\somepath\my readonly folder"
```

Comment: Note the read-only status of a folder generally won't cause any issues and can usually be ignored.

Comment: Its interesting that they chose the read-only attribute to hint to Explorer to load `desktop.ini` for that folder. That emphasizes that normal applications really are not supposed to pay attention to it.

Answer (score 3):

Type `Win+R cmd ENTER` to get a shell. In the shell, type the following:

```
> cd "C:\Path\To\Read-Only\Folder"
> attrib -R /S /D
```

The /S and /D are needed to recurse into and remove read-only attribute from subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/24940/why-cant-i-remove-the-read-only-flag-from-a-windows-xp-or-windows-2000-folder.html

> - Start a registry editor (e.g., regedit.exe).
> - Navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer subkey.
> - Select New -> DWORD Value from the Edit menu.
> - Enter a name of 
>        `UseSystemForSystemFolders`
>     and press Enter.
> - Double-click the new value, set it to 1, and click OK.
> - Close the registry editor.
> - Reboot the machine for the changes to take effect.

Once you've done this you should be able to change your folder permissions.