# Read only attribute of folders can't be removed

Tags: windows-7, zip, 7-zip

I have a ZIP file containing an Eclipse workspace. When I unzip it, all the extracted **folders** have read only attribute set to true. When I uncheck "read only" in properties dialog and click apply, the attribute seems to be removed. However, when I reopen properties dialog, I find it checked again.

Eclipse doesn't accept a read only folder as workspace.

It is important to note that:

- Only folders have read only attribute, files don't.
- I use Windows 7, for unzipping I have used 7zip.
- I have tried to remove the attribute from command line using the command: `attrib -r -s C:\pathToFolder`, but it did not work as well.

Comment: Have you read this? [Read Only flag. A property of the folder, too? (not just file objects?)](http://superuser.com/questions/511487/read-only-flag-a-property-of-the-folder-too-not-just-file-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell ATTRIB to process directories. Also, if it is every folder in your workspace you should make ATTRIB recursive:

```
ATTRIB -R "C:\pathToFile" /S /D
```

/D specifies to process folders and /S processes all subfolders.

Note that the switches have to follow the path.